# Differences between Sprite and Overlay

Tags: graphics, overlay, sprite, video-processing, direct3d

Im on a task debugging the display plane configuration. In the code, I came across display-planes, sprite-planes and overlays. According to my knowledge Overlay constitutes the video data (for example) and the sprite will be the plane (in Hardware) that displays that data (video) when running. But sometimes, instead of sprite/sprite-planes simply overlay/overlay-planes are used. So, confusion occurs here which one will be used when. I need the clarification.